# Transforming <span style="font-weight:bold">some text<span> into <b>some text</b> in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, dom-manipulation

As title, If I have some html `<p><span style="font-style:italic">abcde</span><span style="font-weight:bold">abcde</span></p>`, I want to strip the style tags and transform them into html tags, so to make it become `<p><i>abcde</i><b>abcde</b></p>`. How can I do that in PHP?

I notice that when I open the html in CKEditor, this kind of transformation is done automatically. But I want to do it in backend PHP. Thanks.

Comment: have you try with https://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = '<p><span style="font-style-italic;font-weight:bold">abcde</span><span style="font-weight:bold">abcde</span></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$str = '';
$results = $xp->query('//span');
if($results->length>0){
    foreach($results as $result){
        $style = $result->getAttribute("style");
        $style_arr = explode(";",$style);
        $style_template = '%s';
        if(count($style_arr)>0){
            foreach($style_arr as $style_item){
                if($style_item == 'font-style-italic'){
                    $style_template = '<i>'.$style_template.'</i>';
                }
                if($style_item == 'font-weight:bold'){
                    $style_template = '<b>'.$style_template.'</b>';
                }
            }
        }
        $str .= sprintf($style_template,$result->nodeValue);
    }
}
$str = '<p>'.$str.'</p>';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain your answer to improve its quality (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering for more).

Answer (score -2):

You can also use html tags under php parameters or php opening and closing tags like this

```
<?php
    echo"<h1>Here is Heading h1 </h1>"; 
 ?>
```

***Or you can Put your html code in " " after echo
Like this***

`<?php 
echo"Your Html Code Here";
      ?>`

Comment: Can you please explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be remotely related to the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);
```

Match a `<` follow by one or more and not `>` until space came and the `style="anything"` reached. The `/i` will work with capital STYLE and `$1` will leave the tag as it is, if the tag does not include `style=""`. And for the single quote `style=''` use this:

```
(<[^>]+) style=("|').*?("|')
```

Comment: Not sure if something like *fb/sk.developers for more info* should be part of the answer - if they need more help then that should be done on here (some may consider this SPAM).